# IDA Python + Qt. How can I insert my own tab into IDA main tab widget?

Tags: python, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I'm developing my first IDA Pro plugin in Python 3 + PyQt5 using IDA API.

Now I'm able to create any detached window (QMainWindow, QDialog, etc.) with any contents but I want to insert it into the IDA main tab widget (like "IDA View-A", "Hex View-1", etc.) (see Image 1 with IDA built-in script editor) or somehow add a gray bar "Drag this title to dock somewhere else" in the top of the window (see Image 2). Is there any API function for that?

Thanks.

Image 1

[image: image 1]

Image 2

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. It's IDA API class `ida_kernwin.PluginForm`.

Here is a blog post that shows the usage example. It's from 2010, but it still works: https://hex-rays.com/blog/ida-pro-python-and-qt/

Just a little remark, to use it with PyQt instead of PySide you should call `self.FormToPyQtWidget()` instead of `self.FormToPySideWidget()` in `OnCreate()` method.